# Do custom price logic during ordering based on customer's choices of options?

Tags: orders, price, custom-options

I'm new to Magento.  What I need is to calculate a new base price for an item, depending on the options chosen when ordering/adding to cart.

Example:
Customer chooses a cable.  Customer picks 4, 8, or 12 cores.  Customer specifies a length between 1 and 1000m.  The core option will affect the price per meter, which is why I need to do some custom logic when ordering to update the base price (unless there's some way to do this in stock Magento + Advanced Product Options extension).

So my plan was to create a "core" option, with child "length" options for each core option.  These length children will use the price field for the price per meter.  Then when ordering, I would use the child of the selected core option to get the price per meter and math to apply the price per meter to the input length amount.  Then update the base price for the item.

Would something like this work?  Any suggestions of going about doing this?  I don't expect a full tutorial, just something to point in the right direction because I'm a little overwhelmed with the way Magento's codebase is structured.

**Update:** I've discovered the _applyOptionsPrice method in Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php

However, changes to this do not seem to affect the final price... Is there something else I need to do?